# Run Python Script in a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, python, python-3.x

I have a python already written. In order to run it, it needs some arguments to be INPUT into the command line.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do an online CLI in a webpage via JS and/or PHP so not only me but also someone else who has absolutely no experience on programming can use it easily.

PS: All required arguments will be prompted to user to let the user input it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not possible without setting up a backend server and having your javascript communicate with the backend, sending the data to the backend (from whatever input field) and using that user data to execute the script.

This is usually something difficult to accomplish because you would need to ensure that people can't just enter whatever they want and execute any arbitrary code on your server.

I would suggest making a website that runs this script on its own and serves the output to the user based on sanitized inputs.